# Codename One - Open a picker taping a Label

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to open a picker taping a Label? For example, I have a text "Change the language" and I want to open a String picker to select the language after taping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better approach:

```
Button iLookLikeALabel = new Button("You think this is a label", "Label");
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean something like this?
        Button selectNewLanguage = new Button("DIFFERENT-LANGUAGE", "Label");
        Picker languagePicker = new Picker();
        selectNewLanguage.addActionListener(l -> {
            languagePicker.pressed();
            Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            });
            languagePicker.released();
        });

Comment: I don't understand why you would need the whole invoke and block stuff??? Why fire a "released" event?

Comment: Because this is my (incorrecct?) way to simulate a taping of the picker to open it when the user taps the button styled as a label. Can you indicate me a more correct way to accomplish it? Thank you :)

Comment: The action event already happens on release so tapping already happened. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish? If you want a UI effect this should be implemented in the styling

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish that when the user taps a Button (styled like a Label), the Picker will open (exactly as if the user taps the Picker directly). That's why I added an addActionListener to the Button that simulates a tapping of the Picker. Is this wrong?

Comment: OK, now I understand. You don't need a sleep. Just `languagePicker.pressed(); languagePicker.released();`.